# Equivalent to "Content" build action for xamarin.android? warning XA0101

Tags: build, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I need to copy 2 text files to /Data subfolder on `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`. This work with iOS when set the files to "Content".

But when run the Android version, the files are not deployed and I get a warning:

Build succeeded.

```
../Data/CommandsClient.sql : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
../Data/DBClient.sql : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
```

What I can do to make it work as with the iOS Version?

Comment: put them in Assets - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/

Comment: It not get copied to Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal. Where is located?

Comment: they don't get copied automatically, you have to do it yourself on App startup.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/building-apps/build-process/#Content